# WebApi not loading in ASP.NET Core RC2 project

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

We are facing some issue in loading/hosting of the WebAPI services after migrating to RC2. Prior migrations the same WebAPI was working fine. We have followed the steps for migrations from the following [URL](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/migration/rc1-to-rc2.html)

When I try to launch the application in IISExpress in debug mode, I am able to debug the application i.e. Program.cs is getting executed, then the control goes to the startup.cs methods/events then finally comes back to execute the statement host.Run(); in the program.cs file.
But after executing this statement I am not able to get/debug any statement which gets executed in the background, but finally what I can sense is internally it is getting to infinte loop in the background and the services are not launched. I haven't tried hosting in the IIS, first step of working in the IISExpress itself is not working here.
The below code I have it in the Program.cs file

```
 public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var host = new WebHostBuilder()
                .UseKestrel()
                .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                .UseIISIntegration()
                .UseStartup<Startup>()
                .Build();

            host.Run();
        }
```

Any ideas what is happening here and where could be the issue?

Note: The same steps of migrations have worked for some other WebAPI project, the problem is only in this application

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution, the issue was I haven't got the correct web.config settings
the correct config settings are

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModule" resourceType="Unspecified"/>
    </handlers>
    <aspNetCore processPath="%LAUNCHER_PATH%" arguments="%LAUNCHER_ARGS%" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" forwardWindowsAuthToken="false"/>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```